# Enable gzip compression in magento htaccess , gtmatrix is

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, optimization

[image]

I used almost all code witch is available on net
like

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

AND

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
   mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
  # compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

 # remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
  </IfModule>
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

AND

Step 1: Gzip Compression For Magento

You will need to enable Gzip Compression. To do this simple find this piece of code and uncomment it:

```
############################################

## enable resulting html compression

    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

############################################
```

What I mean by uncomment it is to remove the # from the line (#php_flag zlib.output_compression on) once that is done simple save and re-upload the htaccess file.

Step Two: (optional) Compressing CSS and JavaScript files

Next we want to compress items such as CSS and javascript etc. Simply add the following lines of text directly into the htaccess file.

ENABLE THIS

AND

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Removing browser bugs for older browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you want to have more suggestions and answers please consider to reformulate and reformat your question. As is it is difficult to read. Explain your problem in the beginning, post your code and the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have the right modules enabled on your server.

I assume you are using apache.

Please check wich modules are enabled with the following command: `apachectl -M`

If mod expires, deflate and gzip are not listed please enable them with the following commands: `sudo a2enmod expires`, `sudo a2enmod deflate` and `sudo a2enmod gzip` after these commands you need to run `sudo service apache2 restart`

After you have enabled the modules and restarted apache please check your score again.